# How to make www.sitename.com to www2.sitename.com?

Tags: ssl, redirect, nginx, configuration, subdomain

Sorry to bother you with this, you've been a great community to learn from and I am very thankful. However, I couldn't find a solution to a task I'm having.

I want to change my domain from https://www.sitename.com to https://www2.sitename.com

Do you have any idea how I could do that? Any help would be immensely appreciated!

I am using nginx on ubuntu 16.04.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I have to use Cloudflare.

My current configuration:

```
server{
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {

    #Ports
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    #Server name
    server_name www2.example.com www.example.com example.com;
}
```

So far I am able to open what I want from www2.example.com but I need to redirect www.example.com example.com to www2.example.com

Comment: Do you want to redirect all the request that come to `https://www.sitename.com/` to go to `https://www2.sitename.com/` ?

Comment: Yes, and if a request comes for  https:// www. sitename.com/contact to go to https:// www2. sitename.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect then, in your nginx.conf you should do this

```
server {
  server_name https://www.sitename.com/; // Old domain
  return 301 https://www2.sitename.com/$request_uri; // New domain
}
```

Comment: But I have two server blocks and if I do this it is not working.

Comment: Can you update your question with your configuration you have tried. Why do you have 2 blocks ? All you need is for redirecting from old domain to new domain, and you can pass listen option.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to do it like this:

```
server{
    #Ports
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    #Server name
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    #Return
    return 301 https://www2.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {

    #Ports
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    #Server name
    server_name www2.example.com;
}
```

Comment: This is now throwing me errors unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock failed as server load tops 19

Answer (score 0):

You can set the first server with the domains you want to redirect 
and remove those domains from the second server:

```
server{
    server_name www.example.com example.com ;
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://www2.example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {

    #Ports
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    #Server name
    server_name www2.example.com;
}
```

Comment: Idk why, but I tried this and it is not redirecting properly

Answer (score 0):

> **Step 1** on CloudFlare in DNS section add A record www2 with your server IP
>
> **Step 2** Make your redirect.
> you cay use this way

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
server_name www.old-name.com;
return 301 $scheme://www.new-name.com$request_uri;
}
```

> **Step 3** restart NGINX

```
sudo service nginx restart
```